# Join database tables using foreign key laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have two tables that I need to join in order to access more data. My first table thought_journal_entries contains many id values from the second table emotions. The primary key in emotions is id and the foreign key in thought_journal_entries is em_id.

This is in the Emotions model

```php
public function thoughtJournalEntry() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ThoughtJournalEntry::class, 'id');
}
```

This is in the ThoughtJournalEntry model

```php
public function emotions() {
    return $this->hasMany(Emotions::class, 'id');
}
```

This is how far I've got, not sure if this is correct and how I would join these in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `em_id` in `thought_journal_entries` table, that means that thoughtJournalEntry belongs to Emotions, and Emotions hasMany thoughtJournalEntry, so in this case relations must be declared this way

```
// Emotions class
public function thoughtJournalEntries() {
    return $this->hasMany(ThoughtJournalEntry::class, 'em_id');
}

// ThoughtJournalEntry class
public function emotion() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Emotions::class, 'em_id');
}

// access from controller
$emotion->thoughtJournalEntries;
$thoughtJournalEntry->emotion;
```

If this type of relations is not what you wanted, then probably you have to change your db tables